# rake task and cron in rails 3 with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I am trying to run a Rake task using crontab in Rails 3.0.9(using RVM), But  it is not working.

But when i running in the console it works fine

My Rake Task

```
namespace :alert  do
  desc "create some reminder notification"
  task :send_reminder => :environment do
     p "my task goes here ----"
  end
end
```

My cron task

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/anu-karthik/Documents/billguru/ && /home/anu-karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake  alert:send_reminder >/home/anu-karthik/alert.out
```

But I didn't found any log entry in "alert.out" file

also I have tried with following method

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/anu-karthik/Documents/billguru/ && rake  alert:send_reminder >/home/anu-karthik/alert.out
```

now output is
    (in /home/anu-karthik/Documents/billguru)

I think it is the problem with RVM. How do I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

According to RVM documentation: https://rvm.io/integration/cron

For every rvm or gemset there is an environment file which describes it. You can obtain it with:

```
rvm env --path -- ruby-version[@gemset-name]
```

That is the path to the environment file of rvm.

It is a good habit when running rake tasks from cron, to **invoke them from a shell script**.

The crontab should be something like:

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/shell/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And then in the shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/project
source /path/to/env/file
rake task
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works great. The `/path/to/project` is generated from this command `rvm env --path -- ruby-version[@gemset-name]` just to reiterate what was already said.

Comment: For those who new to unix env like me. Please note that the first line #!/bin/bash is required in your shell script.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to manage to write and deploy your cron jobs.

> All jobs are by default run with bash -l -c 'command...'. Among other things, this allows your cron jobs to play nice with RVM by loading the entire environment instead of cron's somewhat limited environment. Read more: http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/09/07/rvm-and-cron-in-production

Judging by description it should help you.

Comment: I have tried the following one, but it is not worked 
`*/1 * * * * cd /home/anu-karthik/Documents/billguru/ && /home/anu-karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake -l -c alert:send_reminder > /home/anu-karthik/bg4.out ` Note: I am using RVM single user

Comment: What if you try to use that gem?

Comment: Actually Ive been using the whenever gem. Works find locally but not executing on production server. The tasks are listed within cron and set to production environment but for some weird reson they keep failing with an exit status of 1.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through figuring this out for a project:

From https://rvm.io/integration/cron/ :

```
"For every installed ruby and created gemset RVM creates wrappers for basic command line tools like gem, rake, ruby. You can find them in `$rvm_path/bin`."
```

So in the case listed above, you could do something like:

```
*/1 * * * * (cd /home/anu-karthik/Documents/billguru/; /usr/local/rvm/bin/rake-ruby-1.9.2-p290@billguru alert:send_reminder)
```

Where billguru would be the gemset and ruby-1.9.2-p290 would be the version of ruby you are using. This assumes you have rvm installed systemwide in /usr/local/rvm. This runs the rake task in the context of the gemset with the proper rake for that gemset.

The rvm.io page mentioned above lists several other ways to perform the same thing, but this one is the one that worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could just load (use) your RVM environment, which would set the path for rake like so:

```
0 * * * * /home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm use ree-1.8.7-2011.03 rake name:task
```

Where `ree-1.8.7-2011.03` is the name of gemset I want to load, type `rvm list` to see your gemsets.

Answer (score 0):

This script will allow you to run a Rake task from any user/environment.
It will detect the RVM ruby environment, and the right Rails user.

```
#!/bin/bash

RAILS_USER=$(stat -c '%U' /YOUR_PATH_HERE/environment.rb) 

echo "Detected rails user: $RAILS_USER"

sudo -H -u $RAILS_USER bash -c 'RAILS_USER=$USER; echo "I am $USER, with uid $UID" ; echo "whoamI: $(whoami)" ; echo "Running rvm script: /home/$RAILS_USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ; source /home/$RAILS_USER/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; ENV_FILE=`rvm env --path` ; echo $ENV_FILE ; source $ENV_FILE ; cd /YOUR_PATH_HERE/lib/tasks ; rake XXX:YYY RAILS_ENV=production'
```